# can we merge two functions into one in correlations calculations?

Tags: r, correlation

This code worked fine and I got the results which look like:

```
dir1 <- list.files("D:thly", "*.bin", full.names = TRUE)
dir2 <- list.files("D:002", "*.envi", full.names = TRUE)
file_tot <- array(dim = c(1440, 720, 11, 2))

resultscor<-apply(file_tot,c(1,2),function(x){cor(x[,1],x[,2],use = "na.or.complete")})
```

I would like to calculate the correlation only when the `P-value is lower than 0.05`. this function will do the job:

```
 return_cor = function(x, y)  {
    z = cor.test(x,y)
    if(z[[3]] < 0.05) {
    return(z[[5]])
      } else { 
    return(NA) 
    }
    }
```

However I got this error:

```
             Error in cor.test.default(x, y) : not enough finite observations
```

Both functions worked perfectly.How can we merge both functions into one function so we calculate correlation when P value is (certain value, threshold) and also do the calculations even if there are less than 3 pairs.

Comment: Just substitute `z = cor.test(x,y)` with `z = cor_withN(x,y)` in your first function (make sure to define `cor_withN` beforehand). However, you need to modify "return_cor" to handle the case `is.na(z)==TRUE`.

Comment: But you need to remove `$estimate` from `cor_withN` and let it return the whole object.

Answer (score 0):

the question is not very clear,

if you want to do the calculation ONLY if p>0.5,

you can add an assertion, or a simple if before executing the function:

somethings like:

```
 if (IsValid(x,y))
     return function(x,y);
 else
     return NA;
```

where isValid is the function you posted that checks if x,y is close enough for you.

Comment: could you please rewrite your answer in a more simple and informative way?